# Good German phrase for the situation that there are too few resources, and too many people wanting it?

Tags: phrase-request

For example: "Es gibt zu viele Eskimos, und zu wenige Robben", or something like that.

Comment: In addition to what the others said: 'Engpass' would describe a shortage of ressources. As in 'Es existiert/herrscht ein Robbenengpass bei den Eskimos'. Btw 'Eskimos' may be viewed as rude, 'Inuit' (singular: 'Inuk') might be more appropriate.

Comment: Robbenknappheit? Oder allgemeiner Ressourcenknappheit?

Comment: Robben sind knapp, gemessen am Bedarf der Eskimos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bold ones are preferred. The other ones are ok.

> -->**Der Robbenbestand ist für die Eskimos unzureichend.**<-- My Favourite
>
> Der Benzintankfüllstand ist für die zurückzulegende Strecke
>   unzureichend.
>
> Der Wildbestand in den deutschen Wäldern hat sich erholt und ist
>   trotzdem nicht für die Ernährung aller Deutschen ausreichend.
>
> Peak Oil bedeutet, dass die Ölvorräte für die zukünftige Versorgung der Erde nicht ausreichend sind.

**Es herrscht Robbenmangel bei den Eskimos.**

**Den Eskimos mangelt es an Robben zum Essen.**

**Bei den Eskimos übersteigt die Nachfrage nach Robben das Angebot.**

Überfischung,

**Die Robben sind von den Eskimos überjagt.**

**Das Objekt ist sehr nachgefragt.**

Die Robben sind knapp bei den Eskimos.
Versorgungsknappheit. Es herrscht eine Robben-Versorgungsknappheit bei den Eskimos.
Es herrscht Robbenknappheit bei den Eskimos.

Comment: "Unterberobbung" jk

Comment: Be serious, please! I can't think of a good word off the top of my head, but neither "Versorgungsknappheit" nor "Unterberobbung" (even meant as a joke) will do. ETA: So, you added a few more examples. I think it's better, but still not sure it's the optimal word.

Comment: Die Versorgung der Eskimos mit Robben ist gefährdet.

Comment: What about, quite generally, "die Nachfrage übersteigt das Angebot"?

Comment: das Ernährungsproblem

Comment: @FranzEbner :)... aber da ja niemand aktiv "berobbt" sollte es nicht "Unterrobbung" sein?

Comment: @Emanuel I thought of something like "Durch die Unterberobbung des Nordpols..." :D

Comment: Mangel oder Knappheit würde ich sagen. Versorgungsknappheit - wieso Versorgung~? Engpass ist auch gut, wie von LarissaGodzilla vorgeschlagen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express an imbalance between people and food you can use the direct translation

> Es herrscht ein Ungleichgewicht in der Nahrungsversorgung

Comment: Das umfasst aber auch einen Überschuss.

Answer (score 0):

Some economic/biologic terms would be:

Die Nachfrage an Robben von Eskimos ist zu groß für diese kleine Population.

Angebot und Nachfrage sind nicht ausgewogen/ stehen in einem Mißverhältniss zueinander.

Comment: Ein Mißverhältnis kann auch ein Überschuss sein.

Comment: Es gibt kein "Mißverhältnis" zwischen Angebot und Nachfrage. Was es gibt, sind Preisfestsetzungen, die es so aussehen lassen.